# Classifying first-order PDE $C_t+af(t)C_x=-1$ - Hyperbolic or parabolic?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations, linear-pde, parabolic-pde

I need to classify this PDE into hyperbolic, elipctic or parabolic:

$$C_t+af(t)C_x=-1 \, .$$

Well, once there are not second derivatives, I though in parabolic. However, I understood a professor saying that the Burgers' Equation $u_t+uu_x=0$ is hyperbolic (and it has not second derivatives as well). So, I am confused. Is it so a non-homogeneus hyperbolic PDE?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The PDE is $\mathbf{linear}$ since the equation is linear with respect to the first partial derivatives. The general solution is $$C(x,t)=-t+F\left(x-a\int f(t)dt \right)$$  $F$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined if some boundary conditions are specified.

Comment: Many thanks! But I could not classify into parabolic or hyperbolic?

Comment: It's a hyperbolic equation.

Comment: @G.Gare, thank you